# Strange access violation on code exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt5

I am getting an access violation when my code exits. I am using Qt with Visual Studio 2010. The point where the access violation (0xC0000005) is thrown is on the last bracket, "}" of main. What would cause this?

All the call stack shows is "00d3d6c8()". That's it, nothing else. After web searching I saw some hints that it might be called by using release libraries instead of debug libraries for Qt, but as far as I know I am using the right libraries.

Comment: Most probably the AV is caused during finalization of some static objects or objects that have 'main' as their scope. And the most like reason for this is memory corruption (out-of-bounds array access, using/releasing memory without allocation, wild pointers etc.).

Comment: 1. Check the desconstructor of the static objects. 2. Make sure you liked the right version of runtime library, if you have two different version of runtime libraries, it sometime will lead to this kind of problem.

Comment: Next please show your code in such situations like this... otherwise it is difficult to help. We could have pinpointed quite quickly if we see the code.

Answer (score 0):

While using the Qt plugin for Visual Studio 2010, you can make a new Qt project, which automatically creates a static variable "ui" with which you can access all the Qt gui elements.

For some reason I had tried to change this to a pointer, and this ended up causing the problem. So I changed it back to a static reference and now my program exits without an access violation. Thanks for the help in the comments!